# Total price calculation by quantity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know this is a very basic question. But I didn't find the answer on the internet.

Here is my database:

```
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->double('total')->nullable();
```

I just want to calculate the total price by multiplying price * quantity.

Where should I do this? In controller or model?

Here is the controller:

```
        Item::create([
        'quantity' => $request->get('quantity'),
        'price' => $request->get('price'),
    ]);
```

Thanks

Comment: which framework have you used? I suggest you will do it on model part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model, so the method can be reused in multiple routes/controllers. Something like this:

```
public function setTotal() {
    $this->total = $this->price * $this->quantity;
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->price = 10.0;
$item->quantity = 5;
$item->setTotal();
$item->save();
```

You can add `setTotal()` to an override of the `save()` method or to the setters of the quantity and price fields, then you won't need to call it explicitly in the controller. There are a lot of options here, I am just showing one workable one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me $model in the controller? Should I put it on create? 

`Item::create([
       
            'quantity' => $request->get('quantity'),
            'price' => $request->get('price'),
            'total' => $item->total
        ]);`

Model name is: Item

Comment: `$model` is meant as an instance of `Item`, so it would be what is returned by that `Item::create` call and you could no longer need to pass in total, because it is set after creation.

Comment: I am really sorry for not understanding this.I will be obliged if you please elaborate the controller.

Comment: @MarufAlom I added a controller example above

Comment: @MarufAlom Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate it on your controller or you can calculate in on your model. If you want to use model

go to your `app\Item.php` and add this

```
class Item extends Model {

public function setTotalAttribute()
{
    $this->total = $this->quantity * $this->price; 
}

public function getTotalAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}

}
```

and this is the controller

```
$item = new Item();
$item->title = $request->title;
$item->price = $request->price;
$item->quantity = $request->quantity;
$item->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try in controller like:

```
DB::table('yourtablename')->select(DB::raw('(price * quantity) as totalPriceQuantity'))->get();
```